# What is the solution if a parameter for a stored procedure exceeds 8000 characters in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
Create Proc GetProductDetails
(
 @ProductId varchar(max)
)
as
begin
select ComplexId from ComplexMaster where ProductId in(@ProductId)
end
```

> @ProductId Paramter values '1,2,3,4,5........13524'

Comment: A single string that happens to contain a number of commas is *not* the same as multiple strings separated by commas. This is as true in SQL as it is in most languages.

Comment: `varchar(max)` can take 2 billion characters not 8,000 but as @Damien_The_Unbeliever points out your code won't work anyway. You would need to split the comma delimited string or use table valued parameters instead.

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to be using the parameter to pass a list of values, you might want to consider switching to [using a table-valued parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) instead of a `varchar`.

[Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175007.aspx) a [table-valued type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175010.aspx):

```
CREATE TYPE IdListType AS TABLE (Id int);
```

Define the parameter to be of that type (note the necessary READONLY keyword):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetProductDetails
(
  @ProductIds IdListType READONLY
)
...
```

Reading the values from the parameter would be same as reading a table variable. One example:

```
SELECT ComplexId 
FROM ComplexMaster
WHERE ProductId IN (SELECT Id FROM @ProductIds)
;
```